How can I configure an AWS user so that they are not allowed to create an S3 bucket outside the us-west-2 region?
How can I configure an AWS user so that they are not allowed to create an S3 bucket outside the us-west-2 region?

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/easier-way-to-control-access-to-aws-regions-using-iam-policies/  You can also use service control policies to control region use. Control Tower also has region based policies that are simple to apply.

Noted, thank you!
